# Composing Free monads in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, functor, free-monad

I think I understand what `Free` monad is. I hope I understand also that functors *compose* but monads [do not](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/monads-do-not-compose/), i.e. if `M1` and `M2` are monads then `M1[M2]` is *not* necessarily a monad.

My questions are:

- Do `Free` monads compose ?
- Suppose we have functors `F1` and `F2` and their composition `F1[F2]`. Suppose also we have `Free1` and `Free2` -- `Free` monads for `F1` and `F2`. Can we define a `Free` monad for `F1[F2]` with just `Free1` and `Free2` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully I can answer your question:

### Do Free monads compose?

*No*. For the same reasons as "normal" monads don't. To write monadic *bind* we need to know something about the underlying monad, or about the underlying functor in a free monad case.

Hopefully the Haskell syntax doesn't scare you too much:

```hs
type X f g a = Free f (Free g a)

bind :: X f g a -> (a -> X f g b) -> X f g b
bind (Pure (Pure x)) k = k x
bind (Pure (Free f)) k = error "not implemented"
bind _ = error "we don't even consider other cases"
```

In the second case we have `f :: g (Free g a)` and `k :: a -> Free f (Free g b)`. We could `fmap`, as it's the only thing we can do:

```hs
bind (Pure (Free f)) k = let kf = fmap (fmap k) f -- fmapping inside g ∘ Free g
                         in = error "not implement"
```

The type of `kf` will be: `g (Free g (Free f (Free g b)))`, when we'd need `Free f (Free g b)`. You'll arrive at the same problem as when writing a monad instance for any `Compose m1 m2`, we'd need to reorder "bind layers" from `g-g-f-g` to `f-g-g-g`, and to do that commutation we need to know more about `f` and `g`.

Please comment, if you want to see the Scala version of above. It will be much more obscure though :(

### Can we define a Free monad for F1[F2] with just Free1 and Free2

In other words given:

```scala
type Free1[A] = Free[F1, A]
type Free2[A] = Free[F2, B]

type FreeDist[A] = Free1[Free2[A]] = Free[F1, Free[F2, A]]
type FreeComp[A] = Free[F1[F2[_]], A]
```

Could we write a monad homomorphism (a *good* mapping) from `FreeDist[A]` to `FreeComp[A]`? We can't, for the same reasons as in a previous part.

---

### Scala version

Scalaz has private definitions of subclasses of `Free`, so I have to implement `Free` myself to have an "runnable" example. Some of the code scrapped from http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Free+Monad.html

First simplest definition of `Free` in Scala:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[A, B](x: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}

sealed trait Free[F[_], A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit functor: Functor[F]): Free[F, B]
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Free[F, B])(implicit functor: Functor[F]): Free[F, B]
}
case class Pure[F[_], A](x: A) extends Free[F, A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit functor: Functor[F]): Free[F, B] = Pure[F, B](f(x))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Free[F, B])(implicit functor: Functor[F]): Free[F, B] = f(x)
}
case class Bind[F[_], A](x: F[Free[F, A]]) extends Free[F, A]  {
  def map[B](f: A => B)(implicit functor: Functor[F]): Free[F, B] = Bind {
    functor.map[Free[F,A], Free[F,B]](x) { y => y.map(f) }
  }
  // omitted 
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Free[F, B])(implicit functor: Functor[F]): Free[F, B] = ???
}
```

Using that we can translate the Haskell example into Scala:

```
type X[F[_], G[_], A] = Free[F, Free[G, A]]

// bind :: X f g a -> (a -> X f g b) -> X f g b
def xFlatMap[F[_], G[_], A, B](x: X[F, G, A], k: A => X[F, G, B])(implicit functorG: Functor[G]): X[F, G, B] =
  x match {
    case Pure(Pure(y)) => k(y)
    case Pure(Bind(f)) => {
      // kf :: g (Free g (Free f (Free g b)))
      val kf: G[Free[G, Free[F, Free[G, B]]]] = functorG.map(f) { y => y.map(k) }
      // But we need Free[F, Free[G, B]]
      ???
    }
    // we don't consider other cases
    case _ => ???
  }
```

The result is the same, we can't make types match, We'd need transform `Free[G, Free[F, A]]` into `Free[F, Free[G, A]]` somehow.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will manage with the Haskell notation.

Comment: I can't read the Haskell, I would appreciate seeing a Scala version. (I'm also going to have an experiment as it seems like the freeness should let us do the commutation, possibly in a nonunique way).

Comment: P.S. if we use free monads to implement extensible effects, we can compose effects, which can be seen as composing different monads. But that's a bit different and would require another answer.